# rails ckeditor image upload went something wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ckeditor-rails, carrierwave, mini-magick gem.

I'm trying to upload image from computer using ckeditor.
I followed some steps README in ckeditor said, but i cannot find the feature what i want(uploading image from local computer to aws, and use that image using url link)

can somebody help me ?

[this is my case right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxAMx.png)

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITdwT.png)

Comment: Looks like you CKEditor config file is not set up correctly.  First off, do not link to the images, please edit the question to include them.  Second, can you share your config file for the editor?

Comment: thanks for answer. i didn't edit any config file. do i have to set something?